# css three column responsive layout

Tags: css, mobile, responsive

i need a layout who needs to look like this in desktop browser

```
|---------|--------------|---------|
|- fixed -|--- fluid ----|- fixed -|
|---------|--------------|---------|
|---------|--------------|---------|
|---------|--------------|---------|
```

and in mobile to be

```
|---------|------------------------|
|- fixed -|-------- fluid ---------|
|---------|------------------------|
|---------|------------------------|
|__________________________________|
|---------- fluid -----------------|
```

can somebody help me please !?

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first.

Comment: I think you should study `media-query` and play with it. After that put the code you tried for the same. Then people can give you more accurate answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you Google for `css flexible box` and `css media queries`.

I combined the two in this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/18b6mnrs/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes